# How to set width:100% to match first container

Tags: css, containers

Hey i want to have my 3rd container to be the same width as my first. But when i set my 3rd container to be width:100% it makes the width the same as my second container. I will show example code.

```
<div id="container1" style="width:940px;"
    <div id="container2" style="width:480px;"
         <div id="container3" style="width:100%"</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the 3rd container to be same width as first container and i want to use % to declare my 3rd container.

Comment: Why not just move `container3` to be a child of `container1`?

Comment: ok, we know what you want but can you explain the why? probably you are looking for the wrong way to do it

Comment: look this image https://ibb.co/k8CLsSW. i want dropdown menu to be width:100% so it goes full width on home page.

Answer (score 0):

This is my real code: And you can see image of what it looks like on website: ibb.co/k8CLsSW . I want dropdown menu to be full page width.

```
        <ul
      id="MenuParent-{{ parent_index }}"
      class="site-nav--dropdown {% if link.levels == 2 %}site-nav--has-grandchildren{% endif %}"
      data-meganav-dropdown>
      {% for childlink in link.links %}
        {% if childlink.links != blank %}
        {% assign child_index = forloop.index %}
          <div class="col-category col-xs-3" style="float:left;"
            class="site-nav--has-dropdown site-nav--has-dropdown-grandchild {% if childlink.active %}site-nav--active{% endif %}"
            aria-haspopup="true">
            <a style="font-weight: 700; font-size:14px; padding-bottom:0; padding-right:0; text-transform: none;"
              href="{{ childlink.url }}"
              class="site-nav--link"
              aria-controls="MenuChildren-{{ parent_index }}-{{ child_index }}"
              data-meganav-type="parent"
              {% unless template.name == 'index' %}{% if childlink.active %}aria-current="page"{% endif %}{% endunless%}
              tabindex="-1">
                {{ childlink.title | escape }}

            </a>
            <li style="float:left;";
              id="MenuChildren-{{ parent_index }}-{{ child_index }}"
              class="site-nav--dropdown-grandchild"
              data-meganav-dropdown>
              {% for grandchildlink in childlink.links %}
                <li{% if grandchildlink.active %} class="site-nav--active"{% endif %}>
                  <a style="text-align: left; width: 100%; font-size: 13px; font-weight: 400; padding-bottom:0; padding-right:0; text-transform: none;"
                    href="{{ grandchildlink.url }}"
                    class="site-nav--link"
                    data-meganav-type="child"
                    {% unless template.name == 'index' %}{% if grandchildlink.active %}aria-current="page"{% endif %}{% endunless %}
                    tabindex="-1">
                      {{ grandchildlink.title | escape }}
                    </a>
                </li>
              {% endfor %}
            </li>
          </div>
        {% else %}
          <li{% if childlink.active %} class="site-nav--active"{% endif %}>
            <a
              href="{{ childlink.url }}"
              class="site-nav--link"
              data-meganav-type="child"
              {% if childlink.active %}aria-current="page"{% endif %}
              tabindex="-1">
                {{ childlink.title | escape }}
            </a>
          </li>
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %} <div style="float:right;width:30%;padding-left:20px;padding-bottom:20px;padding-right: 15px;">
<div>
  <div class="col-sm-12">
  <p> </p> </div> </div> </div> <div class="nav-footer"></div></ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

I would advise you to separate the HTML and CSS code into separate files. However, you forgot to add a closing bracket on all containers. I have provided two sets of codes, one HTML based and one CSS based.

I have added separate border colours so you can see which `DIV` does what, you can remove these.

```html
<style>
#container1 {
width: 940px;
border: 1px solid red;
}

#container2 {
width: 480px;
height: auto;
border: 1px solid blue;
}

#container3 {
width: 940px;
border: 1px solid green;
}
</style>

<div id="container1">
Container 1
<div>
    <div id="container2">
    Container 2
    </div>
         <div id="container3">
         Container 3
         </div>
```

```css
#container1 {
width: 940px;
border: 1px solid red;
}

#container2 {
width: 480px;
height: auto;
border: 1px solid blue;
}

#container3 {
width: 940px;
border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div id="container1">
Container 1
</div>
    <div id="container2">
    Container 2
    </div>
         <div id="container3">
         Container 3
         </div>
```